# Create Graph By Year

Tags: r, pivot, lapply, country-codes

Each of my pdf files are done by years "Data2007.csv", "Data2008.csv", etc.

In the CSV:

```
Country Region1 Region2
x        200        100
y        120        150
```

I'm trying to create a graph that shows the years on the X axis, the number in the y axis
and have it show each country w/ a different line for a specific region.

This is my code so far, but I'm stuck on how to create this data since all I have is each data organized by year.

```
  x <- read_csv(file)
  year <- str_extract(file, '\\d+')
  x[is.na(x)] = 0 #Converts all NA into 0
  x$CITIZENSHIP <- str_to_title(x$CITIZENSHIP) #Fixes Country Names
  x$Region <- countrycode(sourcevar = x$CITIZENSHIP, origin = "country.name", destination = "region") #Designates Regions for Country
  x[nrow(x), 26] <- "Total" #Edge case fix
  World_Region <- ddply(x,"Region",numcolwise(sum))
  Latin_America <- x %>% filter(Region == "Latin America & Caribbean")  ##Reduces country list to only those in this region
  South_West <- Latin_America
  South_West <- South_West %>% gather("Region", "Apprehension", 2:10) # minimizes data to only show country and the regions associated in SW region
}
filename <- list.files('Downloads/BorderData/', pattern = '\\.csv$', full.names = TRUE) #List of files from 2007:2019
list_LA <- lapply(filename, South_West) #Creates a CSV that shows country, region1, region2,...,region8
```

Comment: Can you add some comments to your code, explaining what each step is trying to achieve? It's quite hard to follow for me at the moment.

Comment: @JCran I just added comments, but all the code really does is go create a larger version of my demo for each year. So if I call list_LA[1] it will list the csv for 2007, likewise list_LA[2] for 2008. It's just edited to fit the countries I want to show and clean up the data.